# Typescript: default export and namespace dual behavior as in Elm

Tags: typescript, import, elm

In Elm, we can write

```
import Html exposing (Html)
```

Then we do not need to type Html.Html, only Html suffice (unqualified) thus avoid the duplication. And we can still use **Html** as a namespace, e.g. Html.text (qualified).

How can we achieve this in Typescript? For example,

person.ts:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

function isAdult(p: Person): boolean {
  return p.age >= 18;
}

export {
   Person,
   isAdult
};
```

other.ts:

```
import * a Person from "./person" 
//Then I want to be able to use both Person.isAdult and Person (as the interface)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today(`2.1.0`) there are no ways for importing definitions from a module using the same identifier. In other words, you can not import `Person` interface and `Person` object as a namespace.

### ES2015 import for namespace

Export the type and a function from the module.

```
// person.ts
export interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

export function isAdult(p: Person): boolean {
    return p.age > 18;
}
```

Now you can use ES2015 import syntax to import everything as a single object. That will look like a namespace, but it's not a namespace from TypeScript.

```
// index.ts
import * as Person from './person';

let person: Person.Person = { name: 'John', age: 20 };

console.log(Person.isAdult(person);
```

Please don't be confused, there is a feature in TypeScript for providing [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) but now it is obsolete, because of ES2015 import syntax.